# How to create a progress bar from numeric values in a database?

Tags: php, html, ajax, oracle

I am attempting to create a progress bar from numeric values within a database. I have two fields within the database, one is called 'NEXT_STEP' and the other is called 'MAX_STEPS' - When NEXT_STEP = MAX_STEPS + 1, then all the steps have been completed and the progress bar should be full (100%). These steps will happen in real time, and the NEXT_STEP will increment as a process in the background progresses. The web page displaying the progress will hopefully update along with it, so use of AJAX will be required.

To do this, I am trying to retrieve these numeric values from the database, store them to PHP variables, so I can then calculate the percentage and display a progress bar with an accurate percentage. Then, making use of AJAX and a time interval, I can call the method repeatedly to update the progress bars.

So, my questions are:

- How can I retrieve a field from a database and store it to a PHP variable?
- How would I go about retrieving multiple rows of data, and then selecting the relevant fields and calculating the percentage? (I assume a while loop, but not entirely certain)

I have tried to make use of oci_define_by_name() to store the fields to PHP variables.

Also, I have tried to use oci_fetch() alongside oci_result() to retrieve the relevant data from the array that is fetched when the DB is queried but to no prevail.

```
$sql='select * from lookout_status order by TIMESTAMP_1 DESC';
     $stid= oci_parse($conn, $sql);
       echo $sql;

       oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NEXT_STEP', $next);
       echo $next;

       oci_execute($stid);
```

I don't get an output where I expect a value to be echoed, so I'm quite lost.

Thanks for any help provided in advance.

EDIT:

I managed to solve it - For future reference if anyone comes across this question, use oci_define_by_name() to define the values from the DB to PHP variables. Then, execute the sql query, and make use of oci_fetch() inside a while loop to retrieve the values for each row of data. You can then do whatever you need to do with the data.

Thanks for the help received.

Comment: What task do these steps belong to? Is it some database operation you're progressing?

Comment: @APC , Yeah, it's a script running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use oci_define_by_name() to define the values from the DB to PHP variables. Then, execute the sql query, and make use of oci_fetch() inside a while loop to retrieve the values for each row of data. You can then do whatever you need to do with the data.

```
$stid= oci_parse($conn, $sql);
       echo $sql;
       echo "<br>";

       oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NEXT_STEP', $next);
       oci_define_by_name($stid, 'MAX_STEPS', $max);

       oci_execute($stid);

       while (oci_fetch($stid)){
         //Some code omitted here...
         $val = round($percent, 0);
         echo $val;
         $prog = "<progress value='$val' max='100'></progress>";
         echo $prog;
         echo "<br>";
         echo "<br>";
       }
```

Answer (score -2):

You use PDO class to get result set from database. And then get loop over fetched result and calculate which you want.